# Can you modify a result obtained via #await?

Tags: svelte

## Problem

I'm trying to take advantage of `{#await}` in Svelte, but can't seem to find a way to make its result reactive (`{:then result}`).

## Example

You can find this example [in the REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/761bd14bc67d49478c87913dadf1b490?version=3.31.2) if you want to try it out for yourself.

In this app:

1. You load some `todos` from the server via `{#await}`
2. You iterate over them with an `{#each}` block and toggle their `done` property when clicked.
3. How do you update `todos`?

*App.svelte*

```html
<script>
    import Todo from "./Todo.svelte";
    
    const todos = [{
        title: 'Todo 1',
        done: false
    }, {
        title: 'Todo 2',
        done: false
    }];
    
    const getTodos = new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(res.bind(null,todos), 1000));
    
    const updateTodos = ({detail: change}) => {
        // ¿How can I update todos?
        console.log(change);
    }
</script>

{#await getTodos}
    Loading..
{:then todos}
    {#each todos as todo}
        <Todo {todo} on:change={updateTodos}></Todo>    
    {/each}
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(todos,null,2)}</pre>
{:catch error}
    {error}
{/await}
```

*Todo.svelte*

```html
<script>
    export let todo = null;
    
    import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    
    const toggle = () => {
        todo = {...todo,done:!todo.done};
        dispatch("change",todo);
    };
</script>

{#if todo}
    <li on:click={toggle}>
        {todo.title}
        ({todo.done})
    </li>
{/if}
```

## Final words

I'm only interested in a solution that takes advantage of `{#await}`, I can solve this problem with other patterns just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<Todo bind:todo={todo} />
```

In context:

`App.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import Todo from "./Todo.svelte";
    
    const todos = [{
        title: 'Todo 1',
        done: false
    }, {
        title: 'Todo 2',
        done: false
    }];
    
    const getTodos = new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(res.bind(null,todos), 1000));
    
    const updateTodos = ({detail: change}) => {
        // process any change if needed (save or something?)
        console.log(change);
    }
</script>

{#await getTodos}
    Loading..
{:then todos}
    {#each todos as todo}
        <Todo bind:todo on:change={updateTodos} />
    {/each}
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(todos,null,2)}</pre>
{:catch error}
    {error}
{/await}
```

Take care not to crisscross data flows too much, though, if you decide to do that.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I actually tried this solution beforehand, but I'd much prefer the props down events up pattern for component communication. Is that pattern not compatible with {#await} (at least for this use case..which I don't think is particularly rare)?

Comment: No, it's not compatible. You can't really do anything with `{#await}`, except display the result, since there's no way to get a reference to the resolved value (here `todos`) outside of the `{#await}` block itself, and especially not in `<script>`. When you need more control, a pair of `{#if}` / `{#else}` and some variables controlled by you isn't terribly more work. `{#await}` is just intended to save some boilerplate in the simplest cases, I'd say (which are actually pretty common, too).

Comment: Understood, I think I'll take the "extra variables for controlling loading and error state" approach along with fetching data in onMount(). Thank you rixo for your explanations, have a nice day.